# Can I support Google's multiple sign-in with App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Currently, to switch between multiple Google Accounts in my App Engine app, users have to logout and login with each Google account. This messes up the various Google tools they have open in other tabs if they are using the multiple sign-in feature.

Is there any way to offer users the option to switch between multiple Google accounts in my App? Like users can now do in gmail etc.
http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1721977

I've had a look around but can't find anyone else doing this yet, but apologies if I've missed this.

I'm using App Engine with Python and the standard Users Service.

Comment: What is your client? The account that they use to login is based on a cookie value that they send. If you are in control of the client you can cache multiple instance of the cookie and send the required one with the relevant requests.

Comment: It's a web app running in the browser: http://www.donebywhen.com

Comment: I've had multiples issues working with this. Until a week ago, I was able to allow multiple signed-in users manipulating the SACSID cookie and setting one per path, then routing each signed-in user to that specific path.

Then this week everything got screwed because the server is not recognizing the SACSID by path, only the root one, allowing one and only one user at a time.

If someone else knows how this could be solve, please bring it on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported. I think it is worth filing a feature request at [our issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks Takashi. I've filed a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8916 << Anyone else searching on this issue can add to that request if they would like the same functionality.